# Errors installing TensorFlow 1.2 GPU in Anaconda env with py 3.6 Ubuntu 16.04 Setup tools

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda, setuptools

It seems TF is requiring setuptools 27.2.0 while I have setuptools (36.0.1)
????

Using a newly created and downloaded Anaconda virtual environment on Ubuntu 16.04 (in another env I have TF1.1GPU running fine) (py362) I attempt to install the TF 1.2GPU, anaconda Command line client (version 1.6.3) Python 3.6.1 FWIW I did install the suggested protobuf binary as I have a rather hefty machine before the TF install (pip3 install --upgrade \
  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/protobuf-3.1.0-cp35-none-linux_x86_64.whl) Could that be messing me up? The error message point elswhere though but I see no solution to the setuptools issue?

I do see that prior versions had some similar issues but don't see a solution? I used the following:

```
pip install --upgrade \ https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.2.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Much installed fine but then I got this and I cannot run TF.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/tom/anaconda3/envs/py362/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg'
(py362) tom@tomServal:~$ pip install setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6
Collecting setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6
(py362) tom@tomServal:~$ pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./anaconda3/envs/py362/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

doing a pip list I see

```
setuptools (36.0.1)
```

So it seems perhaps that the requirements on the TF1.2 install may be incorrectly pinned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install setuptools==27.2.0`

Comment: see the 3rd line from the bottom, no luck... (tried it)

Comment: I see you've tried a different command: `pip install setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6`. Can you try mine?

Comment: HMM Looks like that did it!! Thanks, strange though

Comment: Why would TF be calling for an old setuptools?